# Error: P1001 comming in vscode when pushing db in prisma cloud

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, prisma, planetscale

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`

Please make sure your database server is running at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`:`3306`.
This error is comming on using this command "npx prisma db push"
how can i resolve this error, i already update the prisma project url.

i updated the url, after it doen't work then i created a new project and though new project i updated url but error still comming

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database through a database IDE like TablePlus or DataGrip?